# Android material design customize style

Tags: android, material-design

I see lot's of topic about using material design in android but I currently facing a problem and I didn't found a very "clear" response with an example.

I'm trying to customize my Theme like changing action bar color, button color but it's doesn't work and nothings change.

This is my style.xml file :

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In my manifest I already have : android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

So what I need to do to change the color of different element ? 
Another question, did I need to change something in the xml of the button for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Manifest.xml` is incorrect:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

It should be this:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

You were still selecting the default theme, while you intend to override it with a custom theme.

Your theme is also incorrect. This:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Should be this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

Or this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

You were deriving your main theme from the ActionBar style. The ActionBar style can be configured in the main theme.

Comment: Thanks it works. I believe that I tried the AppTheme previously in my Manifest but I was getting an error because my activity is extended ActionBarActivity ! But I'm not sure that it was this error, I don't remenber exactly. Otherwise, your solution is working, so thank you !